# python working with onedrive api

Tags: python, json, onedrive

I want to write a simple script to load some files from my onedrive.

So far I successfully authenticated and I can access my files. but now I want to teach python to decode those json which I get from onedrive. I just can't bring python to give me back the name and the link from the json.

The URL and name are under the key "`value`" and are named: "`name`" and "`@content.downloadUrl`" I just need these two values 2 times (as it are two files i need to download)

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import codecs

json_raw = urlopen('https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/aFolderInOneDrive:/children?access_token=EwBwAq.....5uqp18B').read().decode('utf8')

json_dict = json.loads(json_raw)

print(json_dict)

print(json_dict["value"]["name"]) #my last try
```

here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getKeepass.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(json_dict["value"]["name"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I know I probably need to iterate over the json, I tried it:

```
for i in json_dict:
    print(i['name'])
```

but I get the same error then.

Comment: It's impossible to do more than guess without seeing at least some of `json_dict` or `json_raw`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case json_dict ins't really a dictionary, it's a list of children.

Just iterate over the list or get a child by index:

```
for child in children:
    print(child["value"]["name"])

print(json_dict[0]["value"]["name"])
```